# Why does this join return [ ] No Properties

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I am really stumped with this.

I am trying to join records from 2 tables.  Easy enough.

Here is my query;

```
return Player::join('played_games', 'played_games.playerId', '=', 'players.id')
        ->where('players.teamId', '=', $team->id)->get();
```

If I remove the where clause I get an array of objects like I expect but as soon as I try to add the where, I get an array with no properties.  Also, if I drop the join, the where clause will get me the records I am looking for.  They just don't seem to work together.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

The join method is performing an inner join on the played_games and players tables and the get method returns an collection of all matching records.

This is a Laravel 5.2 app (should have mentioned that!)

Comment: We can't guess what the methods `join` and `get` are doing...

Comment: Fair enough.  Thanks for replying.  What else would you like to see?

Comment: Can you try this as a raw SQL query and confirm that you get results with it?

Comment: Exactly!  Thanks TheFallen - I have and found where the issue lies.  My mistake for not thinking of going to raw MySQL first to confirm what I was expecting - not actually getting it.